# Hit-Test for Text only Flutter

Tags: flutter, text, flutter-layout, gesturedetector

I am currently working on a Project with some other people where we want to trace letters, words etc.
So we have the Font where the letters look like this (Nilam Tracing Font)

[image]

What we are trying to achieve is to detect wether or not the drawing the user does happens inside the letter or not, this was a Text-Widget before we changed it to the following.

Currently the only way we found is to take the letters, convert them externally to their paths, as there exists no Flutter function to achieve this. After we have the paths we then recolor the inside of the letter.

In the code we then check for the color we added to the inside of the letter (and the paths that are inside the letter, i.e. the arrows and dotted line.)

```
Listener(
          onPointerMove: (PointerEvent details) {
            final RenderBox boxYellow =
                _keyYellow.currentContext.findRenderObject();
            final result = BoxHitTestResult();
            Offset localYellow = boxYellow.globalToLocal(details.position);
            if (boxYellow.hitTest(result, position: localYellow)) {
              print("HIT...YELLOW ");
            }
            final RenderBox boxRed = _keyRed.currentContext.findRenderObject();
            final resultRed = BoxHitTestResult();
            Offset localRed = boxRed.globalToLocal(details.position);
            if (boxRed.hitTest(resultRed, position: localRed) !=
                boxYellow.hitTest(result, position: localYellow)) {
              print("HIT...RED ");
            }
          },
          child: CustomPaint(
            key: _keyYellow,
            size: Size(197.67,
                271.03), //You can Replace [WIDTH] with your desired width for Custom Paint and height will be calculated automatically
            painter: RPSCustomPainter(),
          ),
        ),
```

As this is beyond tedious for 27 letters (2x since small and large letter) and 10 numbers (0..9), we were wondering if there is not a better/smarter/easier way to achieve this hit-testing.
Since the underlying issue is that every Text-Widget has its own rectangular bounding box, and a hit-test cannot be modified to only work on the text itself, instead it will always return true, also if you hit the box and not the "pure" text.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is possible to do, although fairly complicated. Basically, what you're going to want to do is wrap the area that is showing the text in a RenderRepaintBoundary, and then when the user taps you can find the point within that boundary which has been pressed.

At that point, you can call [RenderRepaintBoundary:toImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderRepaintBoundary/toImage.html) to get the bytes of the image, and then use the [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) package to decode that and get the bytes from the point you detected. Convert those bytes to a colour, and that should do it!

There's actually a package you can use to do this though - [pixel color picker](https://pub.dev/packages/pixel_color_picker). However, since your text is static (I assume) and you may need to do a lot of hit-testing on it, I'd advise adopting some of this code (with proper licensing of course =D) and adapting it to your particular needs - that way you can do things like caching the image so you only have to generate/parse it once (as this can be expensive).